# why takes a place "ein- in front of the most german verbs?

Tags: difference, separable-verb

I'm trying to understand the main reason of using "ein" in front of most german verbs.Are there some correlations amoung such kind of verbs, i mean does "ein" charge the same meaning on a verb? e.g. i know "packen" means "to pack" but i'm not sure it has correlation with "einpacken" i'm always presuming a correlation with "word stem" and "ein". Could you please this blur in my mind clarify?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what your question is? Is it the etymology of *ein,* the history of prefixes in general or what linguistic features of German are genereally beneficial for such constructions? Or do you just want to know why it’s *ein* and not *in?*

Comment: I was wondering what is the contribution of "ein-" in a word, and in some words it stays as opposite of "aus" but actually aus and ein are not opposite.

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect this and focus on this? Your comment is much clearer than your actual question.

Comment: Why do you think "ein-" and "aus-" are not opposite?

Comment: because i think "in" is opposite of "aus" :-/

Comment: "in" is not a Germanic prefix. It's a foreign prefix. A Germanic word "wandern" with the foreign prefix "in-" would be odd. Words that came form Latin, e.g. "importieren", have that prefix as it was in Latin "importare". So, "ein" and "aus" are opposites. "Ein- und Aussteigen" "Ein- und Ausschalten".

Comment: What do you mean by "starting point of a verb"?

Comment: German words have prefixes that can change the word's meaning slightly or drastically. English has phrasal verbs. By adding a preposition, the word's meaning changes too. E.g. "to look", "to look for", "to look after", etc. This is kinda equivalent to German prefixes. — And the question why "ver-" is inseparable, and "ein-" is separable (and "um-" is both) is a completely different question.

Comment: @Bergmann Can you give an exmaple where "in" is opposite of "aus"?

Comment: @Em1 main reason to use it,why is stem word not enough e.g. why do you not use only wandern rather than auswandern/einwandern?

Comment: @user1474062 Because "ein-/auswandern" have more specific meanings than just "wandern". Compare "to give" vs. "to give up" or "to give in" in English.

Answer (score 3):

In a way *auswandern* can be seen as a shortened ***heraus***wandern. In the same way *einwandern* is short for ***herein***wandern. And *heraus* and *herein* are of course opposites.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.